# Add termination time to Kubernetes resources

Tags: kubernetes

## Description

I am creating an application where I need to deploy some specific charts to kubernetes with a limited life time (e.g. 1 hour) and also be able to extend their duration.

In my REST API I can deploy charts using helm SDK. However I am struggling in finding a way of limiting the time of already defined kubernetes resources.

### Ideas

Both of my ideas rely on adding a new annotation to resources as in the example below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    termination-time: 1690912997 # UNIX timestamp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.14.2
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

1. Create a go app that uses kubernetes go client that periodically listens for all resources with that specific annotation and programatically delete the resources.
2. Create a custom operator that does pretty much the same (using operator sdk or kubebuilder).

### Problems

Each approach has inconveniences:

1. I would like to deploy it to Operatorhub so I am not sure if is possible to do it without operator-sdk.
2. Using operator-sdk to listen for resource events only allow me to listen to specific Resource (`operator-sdk create api --group=core --version='v1' --kind=Pod --controller=true --resource=false`). I could use that for all the resources I would like to listen. However can't use it with Ingress resources since it does not allow `networking.k8s.io/v1` version

### Question

Are those aproaches feasable?, is there a better way to do it or how to overcome the problems before mentioned?